# Boolean function problems

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, boolean

Having trouble with my boolean function. When I compile the program everything runs just fine, yet when I type in "no" it still says "what can I help you with?".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //size()
#include <cctype> //isdigit()
using namespace std; //(xxx)xxx-xxxx

bool verification(string yesOrno)
{
    if(yesOrno == "yes")return(true);
    else               return(false);
}

int main()
{
    string yesOrno;

    cout <<"Do you need more help\n";
    cin >> yesOrno;

    if(!verification(yesOrno))cout <<"What can I help you with?\n";

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `!false` is?

Comment: On a side note, you can make the verification evaluation a lot simpler by using `return (yesOrno == "yes");` instead of adding in the extra step and complicating things unnecessarily.

Comment: @DrewDormann That answer is.... `true`

Comment: The comments on lines 2 and 4 are cryptic

Comment: @MattMcNabb I read that as meaning *"comment 2 and 4 (to this question) are cryptic"*, and ... spent a good minute just appreciating such a meta-observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is backwards - `verification` returns `false` for anything that isn't `"yes"`. Since `"no"` isn't `"yes"`, `verification("no")` returns `false`, and in the `main` function you print out this message if `!verification("no")`, which evaluates to `true`.

Seems like you should drop the `!` operator from the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you type yes?
Whats happening is when you type no, it returns false. Which you then reverse (!) to true. It works fine but youre flipping it, so instead of only working on "yes", it actually works on everything but " yes".

Remove the ! (Not operator) and it will work as you expect.